# Inconsistent results when piping command outputs

Tags: docker, go, debian

I am executing a command (which is actually various bash scripts) inside a Debian docker container running Docker Desktop for Windows and getting the output like this:

```
func execute(cmd *exec.Cmd, write func([]byte)) {
    cmdReader, err := cmd.StdoutPipe()
    if err != nil {
        write([]byte(fmt.Sprintf("error getting stdout pipe: %v", err)))
        return
    }
    cmd.Stderr = cmd.Stdout

    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(cmdReader)

    go func() {
        for scanner.Scan() {
            write(scanner.Bytes())
        }
    }()

    err = cmd.Start()
    if err != nil {
        write([]byte(err.Error()))
        return
    }

    err = cmd.Wait()
    if err != nil {
        write([]byte(err.Error()))
    }
}
```

For one of the more complex commands/scripts, the scanner seems to finish without error before the output from the command is actually finished. In some runs, I get the full output I expect and in other runs it cuts short.

I connected to the container and manually executed the command/script numerous times and I always get the full output I expect so that makes me think something is wrong with this code. I understand that `scanner.Bytes()` returns the underlying slice that could be overwritten by the next call to `scanner.Scan()` but there won't be another call to `scanner.Scan()` until `write` completes so I don't think there are any race conditions here.

And to check if the scanner in a go routine was a problem, I tried it like this but the same inconsistent results. What am I missing here?

```
func execute(cmd *exec.Cmd, write func([]byte)) {
    cmdReader, err := cmd.StdoutPipe()
    if err != nil {
        write([]byte(fmt.Sprintf("Error getting stdout pipe: %v", err)))
        return
    }
    cmd.Stderr = cmd.Stdout

    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(cmdReader)
    errCh := make(chan error)

    go func() {
        errCh <- cmd.Run()
    }()

    for scanner.Scan() {
        write(scanner.Bytes())
    }

    err = <-errCh
    if err != nil {
        write([]byte(err.Error()))
    }
}
```

This is how `execute` and `write` are called. The command output is being sent as server side events to a client.

```
execute(cmdInfo.cmd, func(data []byte) {
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "data: %s\n\n", data)
    flusher.Flush()
})
```

I don't seem to be having this issue when I run the container in *nix environment. The problem could be something with Docker Desktop for Windows.

Comment: Is the write function safe for concurrent calls? Does the write function retain references to the slices passed to it?  Is data lost because nothing waits for the scan loop to complete?

Comment: @MuffinTop I edited the question and am using the second version of ```execute``` where the scanner is not in a go routine. ```Run()``` should call ```cmd.Start()``` and ```cmd.Wait()``` which should close the scanner when it's done.

Comment: I don't seem to be having this issue when I run the container in *nix environment. The problem could be something with Docker Desktop for Windows.